# I had installed .net core 2.1.3 x86 and .net core 2.1.0 and tried but i am not able to run my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I found every time error using VS2017 in this case while rebuilding or cleaning the project. Please provide me specific solution..

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1.

C:\Program\Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 135

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Could you please try to explain more what you are trying to achieve, what you have done and what your problem is? Maybe you should check [ask]

Comment: They messed up [the numbering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/version-history) but have promised to try to do better in the future. The earliest version of the SDK that supports [.NET Core 2.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1) is `2.1.300`

Comment: I Found that was a problem with changing the SDK version in PROPERTIES

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever